# Dual of the space of all bounded holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras, several-complex-variables

Let $\mathbb{B}$ be the open unit ball in $\mathbb{C}^n, n\geq 1$ and let $H^\infty (\mathbb{B})$ be the space of all bounded holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{B}$. It is well known that $H^\infty (\mathbb{B})$ is a Banach algebra. I was searching for the description of its dual space, but I could not find anything. My question is if its dual space can be described in terms of some measures on the boundary. Can anyone give me some reference on it?

Thank you.

Comment: Each evaluation $f\mapsto f(z)$ at points in the open unit ball a continuous linear functionals on $H^\infty$. If $f\in H^\infty$ make all the point evaluation functionals vanish then $f=0$. Therefore, the Gelfand representation is injective. It is also isometric. Therefore, $H^\infty$ is a Banach subalgebra of the continuous functions function on its maximal ideal space $M$. Therefore, [its functionals are measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem) on $M$. There doesn't seem to be a nice description of $M$.

Comment: $M$ contains the open unit disc, and many other points. A good reference is Hoffman's *Banach spaces of analytic functions*.

Comment: @totoro Your two comments would make a perfectly good answer here.

Comment: @ totoro Thank you for your response. It is enlightening.